# Could some one explain me the concept of Token bucket

Tags: token, bucket

Could some one explain me the concept of Token bucket. Also need help in solving the below problem.

Given the token bucket size, b bytes; token rate, r bytes/sec; and maximum output rate M bytes/sec, what is the maximum burst time T?.

kindly elaborate on how to approach this problem

Answer (score 10):

Have you read this? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Token_bucket

Basically, token bucket could be used for throttling when you want to limit the rate of something. Think in this way, someone put 1 candy per second(r) in your bucket, then you can eat only 1 candy per sec. If your bucket can hold 10(b) candies and if you haven't eaten any of them for a while, your bucket will be full then you can eat 10 candies as fast as you can eat(M) at a time.

I guess the answer for your question about Maximum burst time T can be calculated in this way. Point is that while you're eating candies at M rate, it's also getting refilled at r rate.

```
t = b/m;
while(1) {
    T = (b + (t * r)) / m
    if (T == t) return T;
    t = T;
}
```

So if b = 10, r = 1/sec, M = 2/sec
then T = 9.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a good explain: https://www.coursera.org/lecture/packet-switching-networks-algorithms/traffic-shaping-by-token-bucket-V07oV

To your problem, we can make an equation base on the data IO: after time T, data output should equals to data input. That is:
b+rT=MT
T=b/(M-r)

Answer (score 0):

```
class TokenBucket {
    int _CAPACITY = 10
    int _REFILLINTERVAL = 30 // 30ms
    int availableTokens;
    long lastRefillTime;

    void TokenBucket() {
        reFill();
    }

    void reFill() {
        availableTokens = _CAPACITY;
        lastRefillTime = system.currentTime();
    }

    boolean CheckRequest() { //thread safe
        if (System.currenTime() >= this.lastRefillTime + _REFILLINTERVAL) {
            refill();
        }
        if (availableToken > 0) {
            availableToken -= 1;
            return True;
        } else {
            return False;
        }
    }
}
```